# Getting the template string from a TemplateRef<string> instance?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

If we have a template reference property in our component:

```
template: TemplateRef<string>
```

How do we get the string?

```
templateString = ....?
```

[This is a stackblitz has an `@input`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xennaj?file=app%2Fmy.component.ts) containing the template.  Attempting to just log the template contents as a string.

Comment: This is not possible. The `TemplateRef` is a reference to a compiled template. The original HTML within it will not be available during runtime. It will only be available once it has been added to the view. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Ah - I was wondering whether it would be possible to put markup examples in a template and then grab it during runtime, syntax highlight it, and show it besides the example.